# going from PHP arrays to Javascript arrays curly braces vs square brackets

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

PHP Version 5.3.14

Declaring my Array and how I use it in my program: (changed into a general code scheme)

I am creating the PHP array like this:

```
$totalData;

getnumSends($SomeObject){

   $dataArray[0] = $someObject->Date //Date is a String
   foreach($anotherObject as $Object2){
    switch($anotherObject->String){
    case "XX":
        $dataArray[1]+=1;
         break;
    case "YY":
        $dataArray[2]+=1;
        break;
    }
  }
}

   //Method just puts an int value at certain places in the array
   //extra code for putting ints in the array

   return $dataArray;
}
$someIndex = 0;
foreach($someObject as $Object1){ //that is very abstract
   $totalData[$someIndex] = $Object1->getNumSend($someObject);  
   $someIndex+=1;

}
```

does that make sense?

lets say I have a PHP array that looks like this when `print_r($totalData);` is called:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-04-25
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-04-29
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 1
        )
)
```

now, I have some javascript code that I want to use for plotting data.  the script wants data in this format:

```
var matrix = [[2012-04-25, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [2012-4-29, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1]];
```

In order to get a php array to a javascript array there seems to be multiple ways, but every way I have tried I cannot get all square brackets. Closest I get is this:

```
<script>

var matrix = <?php echo json_encode($totalData); ?>;

</script>
```

output from "view page source":

```
var matrix = [[{"0":"2012-04-25","1":2,"2":1,"3":2,"4":1,"5":1,"6":1}],[{"0":"2012-04-29","1":4,"2":4,"3":2,"4":1,"5":1}]];
```

is there a way to go from the PHP 2-dimensional array to a Javascript 2-dimensional array but without curly braces? I was hoping to stay away from writing a method that fills in each spot by hand? I was hoping I was just using JSON incorrectly. Any help would be great.

Comment: Make sure in your PHP array, that the keys are ints and not strings.  How are you creating the PHP array in the first place?

Comment: If you `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, it will probably tell you the types of the keys.

Comment: What version of PHP are you runing ...

Comment: problem with casting the key's as int's..those key's are dates and when i cast to an int I only get the year and lose those '-' marks.

Comment: The **keys** are not dates in the sample you've provided. There are two entries where the **values** are dates. The keys are the array indices.

Comment: alright, Im not sure the easiest way to tell what version of PHP i am running.  okay, so if I am understanding you travesty, I don't really want a "key" to be anything other than the array index. that means the keys are ints by default?  every array with index 0 will always have a date and the rest will be an int value.

Comment: How are you creating your PHP array?

Comment: I am creating the PHP array like this:
$totalData;
  //Date is a String 
METHOD(){$dataArray = array();
$dataArray[0] = $someObject->Date 
//Method just puts an int value at certain places in each array
return $dataArray;
}

$totalData[$someIndex] = METHOD($dataArray);

Comment: What is `$someIndex`?  The problem here is either that that is a string, or it not the next index in the array.  Maybe you can try `$totalData[] = METHOD($dataArray);` instead?

Comment: As an aside, it's ridiculously easy to see what version of PHP you have installed, among other things: simply create a script that has `phpinfo();` and run it/visit it.

Comment: thank you for the phpinfo(); kevin, as I have the tagline of NOOB as you may have guessed.

PHP Version 5.3.14

Comment: Either use `$totalData[] = ...` or `array_push($totalData, ...)`.  Prefer the first one if you're only pushing one value.  Let the array create the indices and you should be fine, but you're either hardcoding strings in there, calling them out of order, or it's being interpreted funnily.  Alternatively, manually create your date arrays.  `$arr = array($someObj->Date, $someInt1, $someInt2, $someInt3);` `$outerArr[] = $arr;`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I did: `$totalData = array(array('2012-04-25', 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), array('2012-04-29', 4, 4, 2, 1, 1));
  echo json_encode($totalData);` and the output was `[["2012-04-25",2,1,2,1,1,1],["2012-04-29",4,4,2,1,1]]`

Comment: And I tried it with PHP 5.3.15 and 5.4.6, it was the same in both.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the parts of `METHOD()` that you don't show in your question. You may be using strings instead of numbers as the sub-array indices, so it's creating an object instead of an array.

Comment: alright, I am getting closer, I'll update my question to reflect what I changed, and the new output i am seeing. I finally get 2 brackets, but can't seem to convince php that I don't want string key's but indices only.

Comment: fixed it by turning the entire array into a hardcoded string. didn't lose much speed, but for my application, it seems to be sufficient. I was just a little disappointed in the effects of JSON encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Attacking this from the other end:

I know you said you don't want to have to manually reconstruct the array, but here's an approach to doing just that as a last resort:

```
var matrix = [{"0":"2012-04-25","1":2,"2":1,"3":2,"4":1,"5":1,"6":1},{"0":"2012-04-29","1":4,"2":4,"3":2,"4":1,"5":1}];

var retArray = new Array();
var tmpArr1 = new Array();
var tmpArr2 = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < retArray.length; ++i) {
    for(property in matrix[i]) {
        (i === 0) ? tmpArr1.push(matrix[i][property]) : tmpArr2.push(matrix[i][property]);
    }
}

retArray.push(tmpArr1);
retArray.push(tmpArr2);
```

It can likely be cleaned up/made more abstract, but that's the general approach.

Answer (score 0):

One possible, yet not very "clean" approach would be to implode the arrays conveniently

```
function getJSArray($data){
    $jsMatrix = '[';
    foreach($data as $key => $val){
        $jsMatrix .= '[' . implode(', ', $val) . ']';
        if($key != count($data)-1)
            $jsMatrix .= ', ';
    }
    $jsMatrix .= ']';
    return $jsMatrix;
}
```

And then

```
<script>
    var matrix = <?php echo getJSArray($totalData); ?>;
</script>
```

With an array like

```
$data = array(array('2012-04-25', 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
              array('2012-04-29', 4, 4, 2, 1, 1)
             );
```

You would have the output

```
<script>
    var matrix = [[2012-04-25, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [2012-04-29, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1]]
</script>
```